# How to submit a dunamically added form via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am submitting form using `jQuery 1.6` somthing like this:

```
jQuery('form.AjaxForm').submit( function() {

    $.ajax({
        url     : $(this).attr('action'),
        type    : $(this).attr('method'),
        dataType: 'json',
        data    : $(this).serialize(),
        success : function( data ) {                    
                    alert("success");   
                  },
        error   : function( xhr, err ) {
                    alert("error");                     
                  }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Above jQuery code is working perfectly for me.

**But** now problem is that my form is added dynamically on webpage. In that case above code is not working. I also tried `.live()` function but still it is not working for me:

```
// Ajax Forms
jQuery('form.AjaxForm').live( 'submit', function() {            
    // using jquery $.ajax() here;
    return false;
});
```

I don't know why `.live()` function is not working with form submit event.

Any Idea ??

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're calling that code _after_ adding the form to the page? If the form isn't there when that code is run, it definitely won't work. Also, it would help to post the code you use to add the form.

Comment: @GabrielSantos: jsfiddles with an entire form being returned via AJAX wouldn't be easy

Comment: Yes yes, but some codes are so useful.

Comment: Added the complete code that is working but when I use `.live()`, it do nothing.

Comment: Are you using `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`?

Answer (score 1):

It must be something wrong with your setup, jQuery works fine, double check your class name, make sure your jQuery is called after DOM ready ( $(function() {}); ) and all the usual tests.

See link below for example of it working with a form added dynamically.

http://jsfiddle.net/m9VVR/

Comment: same SETUP is working when I use `jQuery('form.AjaxForm').submit( function() {}` But when I change it to `jQuery('form.AjaxForm').live( 'submit', function() {}`, It do nothing. Not submit form even normally

Comment: If it works when the form is not dynamically inserted into the page then it's not the same setup as such. Do both page render exactly the same if you check for differences? Cos as you see from the fiddle it works as intended with an form injected in, so it can't be jquery.